# Spring MVC directly returns a View skipping the content inside the method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working in a springMVC application. I have a request mapping which is directly returning a view without processing the lines in between.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/testCnt" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public ModelAndView testContent(HttpServletRequest request) {

    log.debug("testing debug);
    ModelAndView mnv = new ModelAndView();
    log.debug("testssss");
    log.debug("test purpose");
    //some procesing here....Calling other methods and doing the required process
   ........
   ........
   mnv.setViewName("returnjsp");
    return mnv;
}
```

So for the above code i can see the following in the log statements:

```
2017-11-26 22:01:56,388 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet DispatcherServlet with name 'SiteServlet' processing GET request for [/mysite/site/ContentTest/testCnt]
2017-11-26 22:01:56,389 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping Looking up handler method for path /ContentTest/testCnt
2017-11-26 22:01:56,394 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView myproject.org.com.TestCountController.testContent(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2017-11-26 22:01:56,394 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'testCountController'
2017-11-26 22:01:56,401 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Last-Modified value for [/portal/site/ContentTest/testCnt
] is: -1


2017-11-26 22:01:58,850 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'returnjsp'
```

I dont see my log statements in the log which is the very first line of the execution. It directly returns a view to "returnjsp" without processing the content in this method. Please help

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: Put a breakpoint? Probably your log level is lower than debug.

Comment: @Bnrdo i can see all other log statements from other request mappings. So the server is in debug mode :(

Comment: @Bnrdo do you think there is any configurational issue in this case? or any other suggestions please?

Comment: @Stack  please do clean and build if it's not a maven based clean your local working dir of your server whichever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timer or a sleep function below the log. lines.

Use     java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit and then:
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);